# How to give a space between model label and model text field

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to give a space between label and text field using twitter bootstarp. 
**bellow is the screenshot**
[image]
I want to give a space between

**User Name** label space **User Name** text field
same withe other field.
how can I do that

**This is my code**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id=addNewUser tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="helpModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">New User</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="AddUser" role="form">
                    <div class="input-group col-md-8"> <span class="input-group-addon ">User Name</span>

                        <input class="form-control" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-8"> <span class="input-group-addon">Password </span> 
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-8"> <span class="input-group-addon">Roles</span>

                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-8"> <span class="input-group-addon">Status</span>

                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio">Active</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default blue-btn">Add User</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**When I am applying this**

```
.input-group-addon { display: inline-block; margin-right: 12px; width: 80px; }
```

[image: I am getting this]

**Css Which I am using**

```css
 .input-group-addon {
    min-width:100px;
    text-align:left;
} 
 

 .modal-dialog {
  height: 80%;
  padding-top:10%;
} 


.modal-content {
  height: 60% !important;
  overflow:visible;
}

.modal-body {
  height: 70%;
  overflow: auto;
}


.modal-footer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: you'll want to add your HTML to the question. Cheers!

Comment: @ potatopeelings sorry i forgot to add the code. Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

**Insert `&nbsp` to the end of your captions**

`&nbsp` is the entity used to represent a non-breaking space. It is essentially a standard space, the primary difference being that a browser should not break (or wrap) a line of text at the point that this `&nbsp;` occupies.

**OR using CSS..**
Provide your stylesheet with a class for form input elements making use of the `margin:` style.

In this case you would use a style on the `class="input-group-addon"` field.

```
.input-group-addon {
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being dumb could u please tell me where do i exactly insert &nbsp

Comment: The CSS route is better longterm, but if you're not worried: `<span class="input-group-addon">Status </span> &nbsp` will give you a real space after the 'Status' text.

Comment: I did the same but alignment is getting  change

Comment: Must be underlying styles from your current sheet that are messing with our ideas.

Comment: Try changing the current class, before adding the new one with same options.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like:

```
.input-group-addon { display: inline-block; margin-right: 12px; width: 80px; }
```

Comment: when I applied the above css the result is something else. please see the edit

Comment: Try `span.input-group-addon` or `span.addon`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.